# Redirect to WebForm with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a situation where i dont want to use querystrings to pass data to a redirect page.

Current Implementation, Source Page:

```
window.location = "invaliduser.aspx?u="  + encodeURI(username);
```

I was looking at using the AJAX methodology but not sure it will do a redirect to the page.

Landing Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="invaliduser.aspx.cs" Inherits="iTask.Organizer.invaliduser" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Invalid User</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.utility.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/InvalidUser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Invalid User Account:</h1>
    <p>Your user account ( <span id="pUserName"></span> ) is not properly setup for this application.</p>
    <p>Please contact the <a href="mailto:email@domain.com">Email recipient</a> for further assistance.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Current JQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var username = decodeURI(getUrlVars().u);
        $("#pUserName").text(username);
    });
});
```

Was going to do AJAX POST method to pass the JSON data to the page but unsure if it will stick on the round trip, as i need to pass the data to the page (without using QueryString), ideally all in the same request so the redirect is packaged with the JSON data.

Theoretical AJAX/JSON Post:

```
PostJsonUTF8(
    'invaliduser.aspx',
    { data: username },
    function (resp) {
        window.location = "invaliduser.aspx";
    }
);
function PostJsonUTF8(url, data, success) {
    PostAPI('json', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', url, data, success);
}
function PostAPI(type, contentType, url, data, success) {
    if (typeof (success) === 'function') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: contentType,
            dataType: type,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: success,
            error: AjaxFail
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Based **only** on the above use case example, what is driving _"I don't want to use query strings"_? Above seems "fine" and unsure what you want to "gain"(?)...

Comment: The ideal situation is that i dont want to pass the information blatantly to the page, via querystrings.  I know anyone that has access to look at the network can see the data being passed but i would prefer the URL look minimal vs having an extensive URL with a list of QueryString value appended to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you can't do normal redirects (301/302 status codes) with AJAX. What I normally do is setup the following in my AJAX response handling logic:

```
function tryHandleResponseRedirect(resp, data) {
        if (resp.status == 200 && data && data.redirect) {
            // force a hard re-direct
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
            return true;
        }
}
```

Which you can handle wiring up with something like jQuery's `ajaxSuccess` function:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings, data ) {
    tryHandleResponseRedirect(xhr, data);
});
```

And then I do something like the following on the server-side in a place where I can process all outgoing HTTP Responses:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var resp = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        var shouldProcess = (resp.IsRequestBeingRedirected && req.IsAjaxRequest());
        if (!shouldProcess)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        var location = resp.RedirectLocation ?? resp.Headers["location"];
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { redirect = location });

        resp.ClearContent();
        resp.Headers.Remove("location");

        // send back a JSON object indicating a redirect
        resp.StatusCode = 200;
        resp.Write(json);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Final implementation:
ApiController:

```
[RoutePrefix( "api/users" )]
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    //GET api/users/netid
    [HttpGet , Route( "get/netid" )]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUserId () {
        using ( var ctx = new DbContext() ) {
            JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var username = RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;

            try {
                var userid = ctx.Get_User_Id( username ).SingleOrDefault();

                if ( userid == default( string ) ) {
                    return this.BadRequestResponse( s.Serialize( new { username=username } ) );
                } else {
                    return this.OKResponse( s.Serialize( userid ) );
                }
            } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                return this.InternalServerResponse( ex );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
/**** 
Return a well formatted API URL for Users
---------------------------------------------
    ~/api/users/get/netid
****/
function ApiGetUsersUrl() {
    return 'api/users/get/netid';
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    ....

    GetJsonUTF8(
        ApiGetUsersUrl(),
        function (resp) { //Success Function
            userid = JSON.parse(resp);

            //Cache Common Templates

            //Load Team DropDownList
            LoadTeamDropDownList();
        },
        null,
        function (xhr, status, err) { //Error Function
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseJSON).username);

            window.location = "invaliduser.aspx";
        });
   ....
}
```

Html/Aspx page (invaliduser.aspx):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Invalid User</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Invalid User Account:</h1>
    <p>Your user account ( <%=Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name %> ) is not properly setup for this application.</p>
    <p>Please contact the <a href="mailto:user@domain.com">User Name</a> for further assistance.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need a reference for the Helper Function `GetJsonUTF8`, then goto [The IT Hobbit - JQuery/Ajax Helper](http://theithobbit.blogspot.com/2014/06/recently-had-implementation-where-i.html)